# Jquery Hover state not showing on rollover

Tags: jquery, html, hover

I have some jquery code that doesnt seem to work ...

When I roll over an image I want the title to show but it isnt.

Please see demo 
http://jsfiddle.net/3Raar/4/

```
$(".social-popup-btn").hover(function(){
        $(".social-name-popup").show();
    }, function(){
        $(".social-name-popup").hide();
    })
```

Any help would be great !

Comment: your html is invalid, ul with div as child?

Comment: You have duplicate `class` attributes too

Comment: if you want to keep that div inside the ul, wrap it in an LI and give the LI a class and remove all unnecessary formatting from it

Comment: your `li` elements has 2 class attributes, if you have multiple classes they must be seperated by `space`, ie `<li><a href="#" class="twitter-tab-signin social-popup-btn">Twitter</a></li>`

Comment: I have update the code using comments above but still have couple of issues.  http://jsfiddle.net/3Raar/4/

Comment: Your HTML is still invalid.

Comment: @PaulOBrien You've missed the point, the ONLY child elements of `<ul>` elements are `<li>`'s

Comment: @PaulO'Brien Could you provide some feedback on my answer, please?

Answer (score 0):

> The HTML List item element (`<li>`) is used to represent a list item. It should be contained in an ordered list (`<ol>`), an unordered list(`<ul>`) or a menu (`<menu>`), where it represents a single entity in that list.
>
> > -[Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/li)

I would suggest rewriting your html to make it valid, ***however***, it seems the best way to approach this would be to simply use a custom tooltip plugin.  I recommend using [jQueryUI's Tooltip](http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/). Then all you would need to do is change the `title` attribute for each `<a>`.

Here is how you would implement it:

[<kbd>DEMO</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/TfZgD/)

***JAVASCRIPT:***

```
$(function(){
    $(document).tooltip();
});
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="social-signin-livfeed">
    <li> 
        <a href="#" class="facebook-tab-signin social-popup-btn" title="Facebook">Facebook</a>
    </li>
    <li> 
         <a href="#" class="twitter-tab-signin social-popup-btn" title="Twitter">Twitter</a>
    </li>
    <li> 
         <a href="#" class="instagram-tab-signin social-popup-btn" title="Instagram">Instagram</a>
    </li>
    <li> 
         <a href="#" class="google-tab-signin social-popup-btn" title="G+">G+</a>
    </li>
    <li> 
         <a href="#" class="pinterest-tab-signin social-popup-btn" title="pininterest">pinterest</a>
    </li>
    <li> 
         <a href="#" class="youtube-tab-signin social-popup-btn" title="Youtube">Youtube</a>
    </li>
    <li class="last">
         <a href="#" class="chartego-tab-signin social-popup-btn" title="Chartego">Chartego</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Hope this helps and let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot for your help. My jquery is in an external document, Can you show me how you would call each class so its specific for this html ???

Answer (score 0):

Your markup is somewhat invalid. Try this:

```
<ul class="social-signin-livfeed">
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="facebook-tab-signin social-popup-btn">Facebook</a>
        <p class="social-name-popup">Facebook</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="twitter-tab-signin social-popup-btn">Twitter</a>
        <p class="social-name-popup">Twitter</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="instagram-tab-signin social-popup-btn">Instagram</a>
        <p class="social-name-popup">Instagram</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="google-tab-signin social-popup-btn">G+</a>
        <p class="social-name-popup">Tumbler</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="pinterest-tab-signin social-popup-btn">pinterest</a>
        <p class="social-name-popup">Pinterest</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="youtube-tab-signin social-popup-btn">Youtube</a>
        <p class="social-name-popup">Youtube</p>
    </li>
    <li class="last">
        <a href="#" class="chartego-tab-signin social-popup-btn">Chartego</a>
        <p class="social-name-popup">Chartego</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And:

```
$(function(){
    $(".social-name-popup").hide();

    $(".social-popup-btn").hover(function(){
        $(this).siblings(".social-name-popup").show();
    }, function(){
        $(this).siblings(".social-name-popup").hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: Hey thanks a lot, the markup is a lot better:) Can you show me how you would make the jquery work for each rollover???

Comment: @PaulO'Brien You are welcome. Sorry, I don't understand your question. It is working now, using *the element next to the button that has the social-name-popup class* (`$(this).siblings(".social-name-popup")`)